# Simon Game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, simon-says

I've made a JavaScript, HTML and CSS version of the memory game ['Simon' from the 70s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game)). The design of the board is not too impressive (I wanted to focus first on the JavaScript part) but I also appreciate feedback on it of course. If you want to see the game already in action, it's available [here](http://codepen.io/yiyio/pen/aWvXVB).

```js
var computerMovements = [];
var answers = [];
var rounds = 0;
//strict mode allows one  mistake per round. false if 'relaxed' mode
var strict = true;
//in strict mode, there is no last chance
var lastChance = false;

var addColor = function(arr) {
  var colorsArray = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"];
  return arr.push(colorsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsArray.length)]);
};

var flashLights = function(arr) {
  var i = 0;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#" + arr[i]).fadeTo("slow", 0).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $("#sound-" + arr[i])[0].play();
    i++;
    if (i >= arr.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1500);
};

var resetAnswers = function() {
  answers = [];
};

var updateRounds = function() {
  rounds++;
  $("#show-rounds").html(rounds);
};

var resetGame = function() {
  rounds = 0;
  computerMovements = [];
  if (strict === false) {
    lastChance = true;
  }
  resetAnswers();
};

var playerTurn = function() {
  //during the game we don't want the player to switch between strict and relaxed
  $("#mode").click(function() {
    return false;
  });

  //winning condition
  if (rounds === 20) {
    alert("You, you, you're good you!");
    resetGame();
  }

  updateRounds();
  addColor(computerMovements);
  flashLights(computerMovements);

  $(".button").off("click").on("click", function() {
    $("#sound-" + $(this).attr("id"))[0].play();
    answers.push($(this).attr("id"));

    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      //correct answer
      if (JSON.stringify(computerMovements) === JSON.stringify(answers)) {
        resetAnswers();
        playerTurn();
        break;
      }

      //wrong answer
      if (answers[i] !== computerMovements[i]) {
        if (strict === false && lastChance === true) {
          lastChance = false;
          alert("You get one more chance...");
          resetAnswers();
          flashLights(computerMovements);
        } else if (
          answers[i] !== computerMovements[i] &&
          lastChance === false
        ) {
          alert("Epic fail!");
          resetGame();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
};

$("#mode").click(function() {
  switch (strict) {
    case true:
      strict = false;
      lastChance = true;
      $("#mode").html("Mode: Relaxed");
      break;

    case false:
      strict = true;
      lastChance = false;
      $("#mode").html("Mode: Strict");
      break;
  }
});

$("#start").click(function() {
  playerTurn();
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: justify;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}

#green:active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#red:active {
  background-color: pink;
}

#yellow:active {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

#blue:active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#mode:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#start:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#show-rounds {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Simon says...</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <audio preload="auto" id="sound-green"> <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"></source></audio>
  <audio preload="auto" id="sound-red"><source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3"></source></audio>
  <audio preload="auto" id="sound-yellow"><source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"></source></audio>
  <audio preload="auto" id="sound-blue"><source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"></source></audio>

  <div id='container'>
    <div class='button' id='green'> </div>
    <div class='button' id='red'> </div>
    <div class='button' id='yellow'> </div>
    <div class='button' id='blue'> </div>
  </div>
  <div class='box' id='show-rounds'>0</div>
  <div class='box' id='mode'>Mode: Strict</div>
  <div class='box' id='start'>Start</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript

The code looks nice and short. I like the comments on the `strict` and `lastChance` variables since they explain the game to readers who are not familiar with the game.

Instead of `var name = function(...) {}`, it is more common to write `function name(...) {}`.

The function `flashLights` is always called with `computerMovements` as its argument. Therefore, you can remove the `arr` parameter and replace it with `computerMovements`.

The code below the `//during the game` comment does not do what the comment says; you can still change the mode during a game. To avoid this, you have to call `$("#mode").off("click")`.

The code `if (strict === false && lastChance === true) {` can be written shorter, as `if (!strict && lastChance) {`.

Comparing two arrays by transforming both into JSON format is a nice trick. But that whole `if` block should be outside the `for` loop.

In the `// wrong answer` section, you have some redundant checks:

- when `lastChance` is true, `strict` is guaranteed to be false, so you don't need to check this.
- the condition before the `Epic fail` alert is completely redundant. The first part is already covered by the outside `if` statement, and the second part is coverted by the `if ... then` part.

The code of the function that changes the mode can be written a lot simpler:

```
$("#mode").click(function() {
  strict = !strict;
  lastChance = !strict;
  $("#mode").html(strict ? "Mode: Strict" : "Mode: Relaxed");
});
```

## CSS

The last rule is empty and therefore can be removed.

## HTML

The `<!DOCTYPE` declaration has to be at the beginning of the file.

The `<script>` element should be near the `<link>` element.

Comment: "The function flashLights is always called with computerMovements as its argument. Therefore, you can remove the arr parameter and replace it with computerMovements." - Are you suggesting to replace arguments with globals? Wouldn't a more decoupled more local code with less reliance on outside variables be easier to test, reuse and understand?

Comment: @le_m Im general you're right. In this case though, the function has so many other dependencies (window, DOM) that it is already hard to test it automatically. Therefore I thought it wouldn't hurt.